# How to find my sharedPreferences xml file for use of getSharedPreferences() in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

I'm trying to have a checkbox in preferences to check if user wants the application to run on boot.
The settings file is called `settings.xml` in is under `PROJECT.res.xml.setting.xml`.
But when I try to use this file to read the checkbox on my Receiver, I can't find the setting.xml file.
I've tried the following combinations:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("R.res.xml.settings.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("R.xml.settings.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(".settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I really don't know what is the correct way ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I get SharedPreferences (notice I don't give it a XML file name):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for saving a String on SharedPreferences:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("your.project.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String stringToSave = "your.project.app.nameOfString";
    prefs.edit().putString(stringToSave, "string content").commit();
```

And if you want to open it later use this:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("your.project.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedString = "your.project.app.nameOfString";
    String content = prefs.getString(savedString, "none");
```